# Rails: How to count model with 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to get data which has 0 votes. However when using this code, that shows only items which has more than 1 votes. Let me know how to get result which includes items has 0 votes.

```
def show
    @item = @article.items.joins(:votes).group('items.id').order('COUNT(items.id) DESC')
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN,

In rails 5 and greater than 5 version

```
def show
    @item = @article.items.left_outer_joins(:votes).group('items.id').order('COUNT(items.id) DESC')
end
```

In rails 4

```
def show
    @item = @article.items.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN votes ON items.id = votes.item_id").group('items.id').order('COUNT(items.id) DESC')
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I have realized that

Comment: The best way to say thank you is upvote and accept the answer :)

Comment: There is still one issue in the answer. You shouldn't order by `'COUNT(items.id) DESC'` since the lowest count is always going to be 1, instead order by `'COUNT(votes.id) DESC'`. If an item doesn't have any votes this value will be 0 whereas the first variant would result in value 1.

Comment: Further more I don't like having SQL in my code so I would convert the statement to `@article.items.left_joins(:votes).group(:id).order(Vote.arel_table[:id].count.desc)`